# 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, localhost, root

Hola a todos les pido ayuda ya que estoy haciendo una página con php y cuando quiero conectarme a una base de datos me da este error:

```
'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

Por lo que intente la primera respuesta de [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41645309/mysql-error-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) pero me daba el siguiente error:

```
Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements
```

Por lo que buscando llegue a [esta otra pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094726/your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements) e intente lo que dice la respuesta aceptada y todos los comandos los ejecutaba correctamente pero cuando quería restablecer la contraseña me seguia dando el mismo error, igual al ver las variables "globales" vi que si había cambiado lo necesario para la contraseña, ¿qué puedo hacer? Desde ya gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué motor de base de datos estás usando, MySQL o MariaDB, qué versión? ¿Tu sistema operativo es Linux, cuál y qué versión?

Comment: @Triby estoy en linux ubuntu, usando mysql, y al poner **mysql --version** me da esto: `mysql  Ver 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por lo que mencionas, parece que ejecutaste `mysql_secure_installation` después de instalar el servidor y eso es lo que hace que se verifiquen las contraseñas cumpliendo ciertas reglas:

1. Longitud mínima, por defecto 6 caracteres
2. Al menos un caracter en minúscula y uno en mayúscula
3. Al menos un caracter numérico
4. Al menos un caracter especial (no alfanumérico), aunque creo que depende el nivel de seguridad que seleccionaste, este podría ser opcional.

La solución rápida es crear una contraseña que cumpla con esas condiciones, por ejemplo: `Password_1`

**Importante:** Si quieres desactivar esta característica y usar cualquier contraseña, incluso dejarla en blanco, te recomiendo que lo intentes solo en ambiente de desarrollo y **nunca en producción**.

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-security-excerpt/8.0/en/validate-password-installation.html), necesitas ingresar a la consola de MySQL desde una ventana de terminal y, probablemente, con permisos administrativos:

```
sudo mysql -u root
```

Dentro de la consola teclea:

```
UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
```

No estoy seguro si debes reiniciar el servicio de MySQL para continuar, de ser el caso, sal de la consola con `exit` y, nuevamente en la terminal:

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql
```

Entonces, ya podrás volver a la consola de MySQL para cambiar la contraseña del usuario, remplazando `clave` por la contraseña deseada:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'clave';
```

En caso de que quieras volver a instalar el componente:

```
INSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, ahora ya pude inciar sesión sin errores