# Cambiar contraseña root en MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Por un tema de un ejercicio, necesito cambiar la contraseña de root para MySQL 8.0.

Actualmente la contraseña para `root` es `root`. **Pero necesito vaciarla**.

Tanto en Workbench ejecutando esta instrucción:

```
use MYSQL;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root';
```

Como desde el bash de MySQL en Windows 10:

```
use mysql;
UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD('') WHERE User='root';
```

O bien:

```
use mysql;
set password for 'root'@'localhost' = password('');
```

Siempre recibo este error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'password('')' at line 1

No sé que estoy haciendo mal.

Añadir que puedo ejecutar consultas en Workbench sin errores, es con esta sentencia que no funciona, por si sirve para dar con la solución.

Comment: El comando correcto inicia con `ALTER USER ...` y puedes verlo en [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/495648/54039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'NuevoPAssword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

o si quieres dejarlo en blanco:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Gracias, funcionó a la perfección!